# A question on an elliptic curve having endomorphism ring Z[i]

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

While reading Silverman's beautiful book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, I was stuck trying to understand some elements of Example III.4.4:
[image]

First, I don't see why the case of characteristic 2 is excluded, what goes wrong in this case?

Second, what makes the ring homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}[i] \to End(E)$ sending $m+ni$ to $[m]+[n]\circ[i]$ an isomorphism in characteristic zero?

I'd really appreciate any hints.

Comment: Perhaps this can help with the second part of your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550792/aec-reads-ring-hom-bbbzi%e2%86%92ende-m%ef%bc%8bni%e2%86%92m%ef%bc%8bn-i-is-isomorphism-if-cha?rq=1

Comment: @AnuragA I can't see how to calculate $[n](x,y)$ and $[m](x,y)$.

Comment: There are no primitive 4th roots of unity in characteristic $2$. In general, there are no primitive $2^{k}$th roots of unity for $k \geqslant 1$, since the equation $X^{2^{k}}-1$ factors as $(X-1)^{2^{k}}$ by Frobenius.